# ggplot doesn't show continuous variable distribution

Tags: r, facebook, ggplot2

I have a dataframe from Facebook that looks like this:

```
> names(postsBrands)
 [1] "from_id"        "from_name"      "message"        "created_time"   "type"          
 [6] "link"           "id"             "likes_count"    "comments_count" "shares_count"  
 [11] "pages.likes"    "like.ratio"
```

I have ordered it in descending order as a function of the `like.ratio` variable, which is a continuous variable.

```
> head(postsBrands$like.ratio, 5)
[1] 2.0874 1.7139 1.4141 1.2978 1.2148
```

I want to plot `like.ratio` as a function of `id` (which is unique value to each observation) so I can see the `like.ratio` distribution.

`id` is a categorial variable that has random unique values like this:

```
> head(postsBrands$id, 5)
[1] "227015499643_10153008578079644"  "123538507674613_843197669042023" "227015499643_10152811559719644" 
[4] "227015499643_10153032875784644"  "123538507674613_978571692171286"
```

I have used this code create a density graph and doesn't work:

```
ggplot(data = postsBrands, aes(x = id, y = like.ratio)) + geom_density()
```

Then I tried to create a line graph and didn't work either:

```
ggplot(data = postsBrands, aes(x = id, y = like.ratio)) + geom_line()
```

But I used a geom_plot() graph and it returned this:

```
ggplot(data = postsBrands, aes(x = id, y = like.ratio)) + geom_point()
```

[Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ2Vb.jpg)

So I think this problems has to do with the sorting of `id` in the plot therefore ggplot cannot graph `like.ratio` as I want.

The data is available here:

[Data frame converted to CSV](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4704767/data.csv)

Comment: Can you supply the data?

Comment: @RStudent just attached the data frame as CSV at the end of the question. Thanks

Comment: Thats not a readable form...

Comment: @RStudent sorry, can you try this one? I've checked it and it works for me

Comment: Not getting your question - Density as a function of ID? Do you want a distribution against the ID or do you want density of the variable ? If just density then you don't need id in your ggplot specification. `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = like.ratio)) + geom_density()` will suffice.

Comment: @vagabond I got the density distribution of `like.ratio` like that. I want to graph the relationship between `ID` and `like.ratio` in a descendent way. Like a negative binomial distribution would look like.

Comment: @toku_mo which one??

Comment: @RStudent it's the link at the bottom of the question

Comment: A two dimensional density is plotted as a pseudo-three-dimensional graphic. I don't know that ggplot2 supports that format. Are you open to other R plotting paradigms?

Comment: Just a note that I needed to use `fileEncoding="latin1"` to get that file to be read by read.csv in a US locale.

Comment: @BondedDust thank you, didn't know about that issue with the data